# Generate a set of random x,y,z numbers, with a minimum difference between them, between defined limits

Tags: c++, algorithm, random

So I am trying a molecular dynamics simulation, and trying to populate a 3D rectangular volume with random particles which are uniformly distributed throughout the volume. Each molecule has a fixed radius r(sphere), where r can be different for each molecule. So I would want the sphere to be generated in the volume, and then no other sphere should exist within ( 2(r+tolerance) ) distance from that point(the tolerance will be really small, like 10^-6).

Also, the channel will have a specified length, breadth and width, so the randomization should be done within those limits in a single direction with a similar condition above i.e. the molecule should not be generated if the molecule is closer to the wall than its radius+tolerance.

I was initially trying a structured lattice, but that would mean I the number of molecules would be correlated to the dimensions, which is does not work for me. So I wrote the following algorithm(I wanted to paste my code, but it doesn't work and its a big, exaggerated mess right now, and has almost crashed my computer once.

So the logic is

1.) For each particle, make max_X=X-(radius+tol). Do it same for Y and Z.

2.) For each particle, generate random number between 0 and max_X.

3.) calculate distance between each particle and create a list of particles which violate any of the above conditions.

4.) Go over the list and re-generate those particles.

5.) Create another list of violating particle pairs.

6.) Go over. Rinse and repeat until the size of the list is zero.

So, it doesn't work. And I need this code to perform eventually for a large number of particles, so I need it as efficient and OpenMP paralleizable as possible. I am using the standard cliched #pragma omp parallel for method in front of the for loop for parallelizing the calculations, but it doesn't work with or without the pragma, at runtime, after like 5-10 minutes of a superpowered fan noise.

I am someone from a non-coding background who recently started learning writing complex code in C++, so I cannot do something fancy like structures or classes or pointers right now. I am working with std::vectors though. Would love it if you guys could show me a way out, and if you are in and around Raleigh, **I will** personally drive over and hand you an ice cold beer. Have been trying to do this for days, and is the only major non-functional thing in my code.

Help?!!!

PS/EDIT: Just to be clear, this isn't homework, else I would have asked the professor by now. Its part of an independent project which I will be freely distributing after completion.

Comment: does your algorithm work for a small number of particles? maybe now it doesn't finish because the volume is too tight, and maybe another randomization approach would be more suited.

Comment: Nope. Tried it for 10 particles. Same thing if I push in 10000

Comment: Are the particle radii given, or are they also randomly generated? In addition, for the step 1 of the algorithm, what is "X"? The result of step 1 is a max_X value, but it's not clear where it is used (I assume that in step 2 the random should be done between 0 and max_X, is this right?)

Comment: 1.) radii are randomly generated too.
2.) Yes, mistake on my part. Edited it. the generation is done between 0 and max_X. X is the actual dimension of the volume in X direction.

Comment: what do you mean it doesnt work? does it means some particles collide in the final list?

Comment: Yes, I think so. It just keeps re-arranging the points. I added a cout to check if the list still exists, and it keeps returning yes, it does.

Comment: To be honest: This is a sufficiently difficult problem that you will be challenged to even state the **problem** accurately. Since you're talking molecular dynamics, you probably have a sort-of implicit idea about how random these numbers should be, in particular with regard to their individual distribution. But do we have constraints on their joint distribution?

Comment: Nope. The particles can be placed completely randomly for now, I might add physical constraints later, but for this time, they do not exist. They just should not overlap.

Answer (score 1):

[CGAL](http://www.cgal.org/) has exactly what you need, but please:

"I cannot do something fancy like structures or classes or pointers" will get you nowhere. We can help you get there but you also need to get aquainted with at least structures, classes and the STL.

Comment: I understand, and I guess it is pretty bad that I said that. I am willing to learn anything. I need to do stuff from standard C++ libraries because later the HPC here does not support adding your third party libraries, which is my biggest issue.

Comment: unless it's a university project, don't reinvent the wheel. if it's an university project, at least use an struct Point3D { double x, double y, double z} to help the code sanity.

Comment: @AyushAgrawal: If you can add code, you can add code. Whether it came from Boost is legally and academically relevant, but adding your own code is technically not much different from adding Boost code. But `<random>` and `<vector>` are Standard (as in ISO Standard 14882:2014), not third party.

Comment: Well, I never really found the correct thing for my application on the site. I need something generated randomly with constraints, which doesn't seem to happen there, atleast not in a way I can put together.

Comment: In case you were talking about the mesh algorithm, yes it is there, but I need something scalable and actually random, which might translate to a poor mesh. No program will stop generating at a poor mesh. And if I eventually release the code, I don't want to have solved the algorithm by generating a mesh and then extracting its points.

Answer (score 0):

I'll begin with a few notes on the approach taken so far:

- first, it should be investigated what happens for a small number of particles (*e.g.* 1, 2, 10), in order to understand why it does not finish.
- what i suspect to be the problem is that the list of violating constraints never becomes empty. Maybe there is a bug in the code, or maybe it is just too hard for the particles to fit in the rectangular volume.
- the combination of steps 3) and 4) seems inefficient. It is no guarantee that the list of spheres violating the constraints will decrease from one step to the next one. *E.g.*, for a lot of spheres, it's likely that each one would have at least one other overlapping it. In this case, all the spheres would need to be re-generated every time, leading to no progress.
- in steps 3) and 4), if a pair of spheres violates the constraint, then both spheres are re-generated. It might be useful to consider re-generating only one of them (maybe chosen at random).

A different approach would be to generate spheres one by one. 
While the newly added sphere violates any constraint with the previously placed ones, retry to place it randomly. If it doesn't violate any constraints, fix its position, and continue with the next sphere.

Comment: Well, the last approach seems pretty smart and might work well sequentially, but I need an algorithm which I can parallelize later and scale up. As an update, I am considering finding the max radius of all particles and just using that as the cut-off to simplify the problem. Not sure if it will work though, and definitely won't help if later my particle size deviations are large.

Comment: One of the issues of my approach, which might be fixed with parallel programming is the following. Assume that in an early stage we place a sphere such that it is legal with respect to the ones placed earlier, but which blocks subsequent placements. In this case, later spheres will have a hard time finding their position. A solution here is to stop the generation altogether and start over when the number of random attempts for a sphere is above a pre-defined maximum number of tries. An useful alternative approach is to start multiple such sequential processes in parallel.

Comment: I apologize, could you please explain your approach in a different way?

Comment: It's nothing fancy, the parallel approach would just consist of running multiple instances of the sequential procedure, independently. Additionally, make sure that you use different random seeds for different processes, so that you prevent the situation where all processes generate exactly the same results.

Answer (score 0):

"3.) calculate distance between each particle and create a list of particles which violate any of the above conditions."

That's an `O(N*N)` algorithm right there. And you're doing it repeatedly. How often you're doing that will probably depend on the density of molecules, but I hope for you you're not simulating a solid.

There is a proper way to do this. Slice the volume in small boxes, roughly the size of `radius^3`. Now you only need to check for collisions within each box, and collisions with its 26 neighbors. If you have many, many of these small boxes, only checking 27 small boxes is far more efficient.

Finding the right box is easy if you use integer/fixed-point coordinates, and a power of two for the exact box size. E.g. if radius would be 250, make the boxes 256x256x256, so that finding the right box can be done by dividing by 256. This is a bit shift in hardware.

Answer (score 0):

There are two good answers I know about

One is generalization of the Poisson disk sampling, called Poisson Sphere distribution. POisson disk sampling was invented to sample 2D points with a minimum distance between them (hence disks).

Poisson spheres was done to do sampling in 3D, paper:

https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/26c3/490a9f2bdf8082d351639ff596f000f8e319.pdf

Answer (score 0):

Amother way to do that is using quasi-random numbers. For quasi-random Sobol sequences there is a statement which says that there is minimum positive distance between points which amounts to 0.5*sqrt(d)/N, where `d` is dimension of the problem (3 in your case), and `N` is number of points sampled in the hypercube. Paper from the man himself http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0378475406002382.

Reasonable implementation of the Sobol quasi-randoms is in the GNU Scientific Library (GSL)